# Return the row and column position of R data frame where the cell value matches a pattern

Tags: r

I have a dataframe

```
structure(list(Brand = c("AB", "AC", "AD", "BA", "CB", "CK"), `&TV` = c("0_640", 
"0", "1_340", "0", "0", "0"), `&TV HD` = c("1_500", "0", "0_140", 
"0", "0", "0")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

that looks like this:

```
  Brand   &TV &TV HD
1    AB 0_640  1_500
2    AC     0      0
3    AD 1_340  0_140
4    BA     0      0
5    CB     0      0
6    CK     0      0
```

I want to return the row and column value of those cells that has the pattern `1_` in it. For the above example, I want to return

```
row col
3    2
1    3
```

I am trying to use grep but was not very successful.

```
grep(New_Brands_Theme_Combine[,c(1:length(New_Brands_Theme_Combine))], pattern = "1_")
```

The above gives me the column numbers of the data frame where the pattern is found.  How do I get the column numbers along with the row numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is loop over the columns of interest ('colnm'), apply the `grep` to get the position index, set the `names` of the `list` with the column index and `stack` it to a two column data.frame

```
colnm <- 2:3
out <- stack(setNames(lapply(df1[colnm], grep, pattern = "1_"), colnm))
names(out) <- c("row",  "col")
out
#  row col
#1   3   2
#2   1   3
```

Comment: Couldnt believe how fast you ingest the problem and come up with a solution....thank you so much....the solution worked perfectly.....I will accept it in 10 minutes.

Answer (score 4):

One `base R` option could be:

```
which(matrix(grepl("1_", unlist(df)), dim(df)), arr.ind = TRUE)

     row col
[1,]   3   2
[2,]   1   3
```

Or even:

```
which(sapply(df, grepl, pattern = "1_"), arr.ind = TRUE)
```